# RXJava2 + AWS SDK: Getting UndeliverableException when calling onError from AWS S3 TransferListener

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rx-android, rx-java2

I am using RXJava (RXAndroid) actually to serialise a bunch of AWS s3 transfer requests.

I am using the AWS TransferUtility which provides an asynchronous TransferListener that gets progress and errors notifications.

I am having a hard time propagating those errors.

My code look like this

```
    for (final String subscription : subscriptions) {

        Observable<String> thisObservable = new Observable<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super String> observer) {
                new S3Loader(subscription, observer).load();
                // The S3Loader uses AWS TransferListener to call onNext and onError of the observers
            }
        };

        observables.add(thisObservable);

        Log.v(this, "Added %s", subscription);

    }

    Observable.concat(observables)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {

                     @Override
                     public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                         Log.v(OperationalStatusFragment.this, "Subscribed...");
                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onNext(@NonNull String s) {
                         Log.v(OperationalStatusFragment.this, "Started weather operation \"%s\"", s);
                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                         Log.e(OperationalStatusFragment.this, "An error happened...");
                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onComplete() {
                         Log.v(OperationalStatusFragment.this, "Completed...");

                     }
                 }
    );
```

Basically, when the code in the TransferListebner calls onError, the observer onError block is called, but the application crashed just after that as I get the same exception that was thrown but wrapped in an UndeliverableException.

It feels like this has to do with the async nature of the transferListener (as if I call the same onError method synchronously it works as expected.

Any idea what is going wrong ?

Edit 1: Here is what the stack trace looks like

```
06-02 18:49:23.286 11687-11687/com.ironbird.fav2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       Process: com.ironbird.fav2, PID: 11687
       io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.io.IOException: Got failed while downloading weather DB for "FRxxx" from "weather/06/weather_FRxxx.db" to "/data/user/0/com.ironbird.fav2/app_weather/FRxxx.db" (transfer #568)
           at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:349)
           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableConcatMap$ConcatMapDelayErrorObserver$DelayErrorInnerObserver.onError(ObservableConcatMap.java:509)
           at com.ironbird.fav2.weather.S3loader$1.onStateChanged(S3loader.java:79)
           at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferStatusUpdater$1.run(TransferStatusUpdater.java:172)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Got failed while downloading weather DB for "FRxxx" from "weather/06/weather_FRxxx.db" to "/data/user/0/com.ironbird.fav2/app_weather/FRxxx.db" (transfer #568)
           at com.ironbird.fav2.weather.S3loader$1.onStateChanged(S3loader.java:79) 
           at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferStatusUpdater$1.run(TransferStatusUpdater.java:172) 
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Edit 2: Here is what S3loader.load() looks like:

```
public void load() {

    observer.onNext(subscription);

        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
        TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client, context);
        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download(BUCKET, subscription, file);
        observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {

                if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED) {
                    observer.onComplete();
                } else if (state == TransferState.FAILED) {
                    observer.onError(new IOException("An error happened"));
                } 
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception e) {

                observer.onError(e);
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Showing the actual stacktrace would be really helpful along with how you implemented the S3Loader. Also why didn't you use `create`?

Comment: @akarnodkd, I have added the stack trace and load code. I did not use create because I have used `concat`. I am not sure I should have a `create`as well.

Comment: What is the version of RxJava?

Comment: Also please use `Observable.create` that honors the Observable protocol.

Comment: @akarnokd, this is RXJava2. Could you please ellaborate a bit on "Observable.create that honors the Observable protocol" ?

Comment: Are you using the latest version, 2.1.0 as of now? You probably have a NullPointerException because how you implemented S3Loader: you didn't call onSubscribe and otherwise don't do anything if the downstream cancels the stream. `Observable.create` does take care of this for you.